# TS: Deconstructing an array containing an object and a function (setter) only works with @ts-ignore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React hook I'm using to set the values on a Context provider.

```ts
const useAuth = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [tryAuth, setTryAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tryAuth) {
      const getToken = async () => {
        console.log("triggered");

        setIsLoading(true);
        const axiosInstance = axios.get<TokenResponseType>(
          "http://localhost:3500/token"
        );
        const tokenResult = (await axiosInstance).data.accessToken;
        setToken(tokenResult);
        setIsLoading(false);
      };
      getToken();
    }
  }, [tryAuth]);

  return [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth];
};

export default useAuth;

export type inferredType = ReturnType<typeof useAuth>;
```

VSCode tells me the return type is as follows:

[image: VSCode snapshot]

```ts
(alias) useAuth(): (React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>> | {
    token: string;
    isLoading: boolean;
})[]
```

Because I couldn't figure out how to describe the type I used the following approach:

```ts
export type inferredReturnType = ReturnType<typeof useAuth>;
```

And I'm initializing my React Context with the following line:

```ts
const AuthContext = React.createContext<inferredReturnType | undefined>(undefined);
```

However when I'm trying to use the hook in a Component as follows:

```ts
const [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] = useAuth();
```

I'm getting the error message

> Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction> | { token: string; isLoading: boolean; }'.ts(2339).

Only suppressing the TSCompiler with //@ts-ignore made it work so far.

Here the code for the Context and context provider:

```ts
const AuthContext = React.createContext<inferredReturnType | undefined>(undefined);

const AuthContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] = useAuth();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth]}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContextProvider;

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (token === undefined)
    throw new Error('useAuthContext must be inside a Provider with a value');

  return [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth];
};
```

Here is the link to the Code Sandbox:
[image: Edit staging-sea-kmury]

What I'm trying to achieve is described under "Custom Data fetching hook" in the [excellent blog post by Robin Wieruch](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data)  just for TypeScript.

I'm sure it's some advanced type destructuring thingy from ES6 in combination with TypeScript that's messing with my head but I can't find a good article / docu to read up on it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is inferring the type `(A|B)[]` (which is reasonable, it doesn't know you're always going to return things in the same order), but you want the tuple type `[A, B]`.

You have at least two options:

#### Define the type explicitly

Like this:

```
type UseAuthReturnType = [
    {token: string, isLoading: boolean},
    React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
];
```

If you use that, like this:

```
const useAuth = (): UseAuthReturnType => {
    // ...
};
```

...your destructuring works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwBEUqDLwDcAWABQoSLDgoAHsAiEOXHr3mLCIiRJgBPMEjgBVYgEF8MABbIY+KADsAKgaMBeOAG0JcX7hgQANZIDgBccIQwUMAOAObYwIQAMhAoACYxseEARhAQADaoDqyYPn7I6DAAdAAiiWAUaFYAPBUYVSRIMGQUSGYYig7NuQVFAHxjEgC6YuISaBAOkQTmllZwHgAUAJThpn1rtvbOrhtjuGULS-CeAcEO2MQwTkEhUxsrpOSUm7y827NfFdlp5Eil0plHl0AJLJVIZOLvDw0Ho-egofLEAGXRYgqJ6CzWKHPKAEtZIz6opCbdGYpDYubiXw0BhMDCbHZnC5MvzAehwTb4wlWbbcvx+YHwWJdF73D4oQh6BxoAWitznHBlcVA3GjKr5CCxX5RYCxaUCNL-WZa7VPWHghFGqL4emA7U666yBRKaHXFDK9xezRVaUwZqykLIQiQJZIFyGMabG3u3hWGAwMChAD0WYNaAxViUMFCAGYAKwABgrWbuIV4yb8DPdHuWtYcUfw+XgWxQAHcUMB4BofX6A9sqmkKCgqug0EhCIQIw43e6nkvBa92-POzAm827XCIXEaRisSu-Kxz75Q+u975WGUSl4heSGWUBHZHF48G2EofHWwxJOKSwozBIl46OIkrfnAv5wGC8KZIBEQyiB5IfDQwo7MIQA)

#### Use `as const`

Like this:

```
const useAuth = () => {
  // ...

  return [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] as const;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwBEUqDLwDcAWABQoSLDgoAHsAiEOXHr3mLCIiRLQQAdoXg0AgvhgALOAF44ACgCUNgHy4JcOHsPwA2jAgA1kj62MQwACqBwQC6NgTEZBRIdry8DmLiHl5GcD7AhAAyECgAJsD6AOahSDAAkoXFZZWxtjSJlHb0KAA2xOnungY5flAAnmaW1RFjExYt8aTkHV29SP3iAzQMTBh2ji5umR5wwPT2MDPmFk44A8eD3nAVNZFB+nEohKP6aPZO1q5bkd7lkhhBukgAHTdCAVFIXYAVZ4CEppDJ3EFhepFUrlOEXfBrDIg47ZeAaJS1bwoH5ID4KJSQ54wAA8r2CyEIkEMSHCozASGcdgxJN4FhgMDAAC4APQymFoHoWJQwKUAZgArAAGLUy-xvXgi47rEmgx76jlIQj4brwWx2FAAdxQwHJDMIVKMNLQa0hJQoKEh6B9hEI7P0xNNYXDdgt+k5NpgJqjNWxjTxnR6fUj91YOeOzJjyY8rAGrGwI3GV2i6wGAhg+Cg7x8eDj2HyOKaFTYU3Cl0ssU+DyMGTzOnEZNyraiIRODVxlR7cGj-bmcVMV0cwiAA)

TypeScript will infer that differently. Specifically, it'll infer:

```
readonly [
    {
        readonly token: string;
        readonly isLoading: boolean;
    },
    React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
]
```

Assuming you don't want to receive that first entry as an actual object and change its values (which I'm fairly sure you don't), that works just as well via inference.

Comment: If `useAuth` doesn't guarantee order of the items in the array (like VS Code suggested), this could fail at runtime.

Comment: @joshvito - `useAuth` is in standard hook form (like `useState`), the OP isn't going to change the order. :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if VS CODE  is just inferring the type from js or are the type files for React not accurate?

Comment: @joshvito - TypeScript's inference of the type is reasonable, it's just wrong for this use case. TypeScript's type inference is pragmatic. It doesn't do the narrowest thing possible even when it could. For instance, `let s = "example";` infers `s` to be `string`, not the literal type `"example"`. (Whereas `const s = "example";` does the latter, since it can't change.) Similarly, TypeScript doesn't know `useAuth` above is a hook (it may well someday, at least optionally), so it assumes `(A|B)[]` rather than the more narrow `[A, B]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the answer! Would it be better to assign the variables and the function as properties of an object before passing them around?

Comment: @Frank - It would still infer `(A|B)[]`. :-) What you have looks good, it's just this is a place where inference goes the wrong way so you have to be explicit. **But**, I realized you have an option if you don't want to be explicit, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ok, awesome. Got it! I just had to treat it in the following step always explicitly as UseAuthReturnType as such: 
`const [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] = useContext(
    AuthContext
  ) as UseAuthReturnType;`
Thanks again! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Frank - You typically want to avoid type assertions (`as UseAuthReturnType`). Your context is defined with the type `UseAuthReturnType|undefined` which means that it can be `undefined`. if it is, that line of code will throw an error at runtime. Ideally, don't let the context be `undefined` (and then you won't need the type assertion). If you need to allow for it to be `undefined`, you'll need `const context = useContext(AuthContext);` and then branch on whether `context` is `undefined`. In the branch where it isn't, TypeScript will understand the destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript infers the return type, but in this case it does that wrongly.

Basically, it sees an array of two objects with different types:

One type:

```js
{
  token: string,
  isLoading: boolean
}
```

The other type:

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
```

So, typescripts decides that the return type is an array of objects that are either the first, or the second type. **But it doesn't understand in which order they are returned, or that the array has exactly 2 items.** That is your inferred type:

```js
({
  token: string,
  isLoading: boolean
} | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>)[]
```

Which means: *there is a variable amount of items that are either a react action or an objects with a string `token` and a boolean `isLoading`.*

When you try to use it, calling:

```js
const [{ token, isLoading }, setTryAuth] = useAuth();
```

Typescript complains, because from its points of view there are 2 problems:

1. You extract 2 objects from the array. Typescript didn't infer the length of the array, so he warns you that potentially those two items does not exists.
2. You extract the keys `token` and `isLoading` from the first returned item. But typescript has no clue that the first item has that type, so it warns you that the first item may be of type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`.

You can solve everything by saying to typescript that the return type has exactly two items, with a specific order:

```
type UseAuthReturnType = [
    {token: string, isLoading: boolean},
    React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
];

const useAuth = (): UseAuthReturnType => {
    // ...
};
```

Now typescript knows that you always have two items, that the first item has both `token` and `isLoading` keys and the second item is a react action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, which is completely correct! @gbalduzzi! @T.J.Crowder was just even a little bit faster.

Comment: Not a problem man, just glad you understood the problem and the solution

Answer (score 0):

dince `useAuth` is typed to return an array containg the two types. e.g.  `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>` OR `{token: string; isLoading: boolean;}`, the  error is telling you that you cannot assign to the property `token`, because it is not part of `Dispatch.SetStateAction` 's signature.

It doesn't look to me like order is enforces with that type. Maybe a React user can help in that reguard.

You could filter/type check the response from `useAuth` so the type is no longer complex. Or update the type if it is always returning that the type with  `token` and `isLoading`.